# opposite meaning of the word timely

Tags: word-request

I need a word having the opposite meaning to the word timely, which means happening at a suitable moment.

But the word untimely means,

> describes something **bad** that happens unexpectedly early or at a time that is not suitable.

This is not the exactly opposite meaning since it describes something bad, I don't want to express this as a bad thing. So it isn't suitable for the below sentence.

> Reading printed magazines is just a way to get to know the latest updates around the world in a *non-timely* manner.

Is non-timely a good choice and what's other word suitable?

Comment: Do you want to rephrase "non-timely manner" into "anytime" manner?

Comment: I don't know, but you can cheat and rewrite the sentence: *Reading printed magazines keeps you up-to-date with the latest in last week's news.*

Comment: @Mistu4u, no. I'm actually not sure about the word non-timely constructed by me is right or not.

Comment: Can you break down more minutely so that we can understand what do you want to mean by "non-timely".

Comment: I want to express it is late, not timely and not fast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### ***[Tardy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tardy)***

Occurring, arriving, acting, or done after the scheduled, expected, or usual time; late.

> Microsoft's *tardy* response to iPhone – After its debacle with the Kin,
>   Microsoft has gotten its smartphone act together with the announcement
>   of its first Windows Mobile 7 phones (10/11/2010)

Comment: "Reading printed magazines is just a way to get to know the latest updates around the world in a tardy manner." sounds very unnatural in my ears.

Answer (score 0):

> Reading printed magazines is just a way to get to know the latest
>   updates around the world in a **delayed** manner.

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of why this is a good choice; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](//meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.